# Scrambled order list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

With a list of dictionaries, in a json dataset (mydata.json) looking like this:

```
[
{"A": "123", "B": "456", "C": "789", "D": "1011"}, 
{"A": "1213", "B": "1415", "C": "1617", "D": "1819"},
... 
]
```

I am attempting to loop through each dictionary, and extract each key-value pair in the order in which it is stored.

I wish to retain the A, B, C, D sequence in that specific order per dictionary to be able to pass them into another piece of code that will process it further.

For simplicity, I'm testing it with printing each step through each iteration of the below nested for-loop.

Unfortunately it doesn't process the dictionaries in the way that I would need.

I need access to each key-value pair, per each loop, in that order, e.g. the first dictionary containing the key A, should be succeeded by the first B-C-D of that same dict.

Then the second dictionary should be processed, starting with A, then B-C-D, etc.

What I tried:

```
with open("mydata.json", "r") as read_file:
    md = json.load(read_file)

    for d in md:
        for k,v in d.items():
            if (k == "A"):
                print(k + ": " + v)
                continue
            if (k == "B"):
                print(k + ": " + v)
                continue
            if (k == "C"):
                print(k + ": " + v)
                continue
            if (k == "D"):
                print(k + ": " + v)
                continue
            else:
                continue
```

Desired output (strict sequential order):

```
A: 123    
B: 456
C: 789
D: 1011
A: 1213    
B: 1415
C: 1617
D: 1819
```

Actual output (scrambled order):

```
B: 456
D: 1011
A: 123    
C: 789
A: 1213
C: 1617
... etc.
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I have indeed marked my question as a duplicate, apologies for this!
If I need to delete it altogether, to reduce clutter in SO, please leave a comment suggesting this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: what python version is this? note: python dictionaries were not ordered before python 3.6 (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6#39980548).

Comment: Dictionaries do not retain the order of their keys.

Comment: Try [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here is some guidance for deciding if the question should be deleted or left as a sign-post for others: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300119/3975963

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of Python don't retain dictionary key order. From 3.7 onwards, it works well.

You could convert the `items` to a list and sort them before you use them in your loop if want - two iterations though, so less efficient.

You could use an `OrderedDict` from the `collections` module too - usage:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

ordered = OrderedDict()
# Now key order is remembered
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the keys before iterate.

I removed the useless multiple if/continue statements and moved the `for` loop outside the `with` block because you should close the file as soon as you don't need it.

```
with open("mydata.json", "r") as read_file:
    md = json.load(read_file)

for d in md:
    for key in sorted(d.keys()):
        if key in ["A","B","C","D"]:
            print('{}: {}'.format(key, d[key]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Below

```
from collections import OrderedDict
lst = [
  {"A": "123", "B": "456", "C": "789", "D": "1011"}, 
  {"A": "1213", "B": "1415", "C": "1617", "D": "1819"},
]
lst1 = []
for d in lst:
  tmp = sorted(d.keys())
  x = OrderedDict()
  for z in tmp:
    x[z] = d[z]
  lst1.append(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use the `object_pairs_hook` option of `json.load` to load in as an ordered dict in the first place.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import json

js = '{"A": "123", "B": "456", "C": "789", "D": "1011"}'
md = json.loads(js, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
```

When you provide the `object_pairs_hook` argument to `json.load` or `json.loads`, whenever the parser finds a json object, it passes that object as an ordered list of (already decoded) tuples to the function provided as `object_pairs_hook`. So in this case, `loads` passes the list `[("A", "123"), ("B", "456"), ("C", "789"), ("D", "1011")]` to `OrderedDict`.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
data = [
{"A": "123", "B": "456", "C": "789", "D": "1011"},
{"A": "1213", "B": "1415", "C": "1617", "D": "1819"}
]

for dict in data:
    for key, value in dict.items():
        print ("{}:{}".format(key,value))
```

output:

```
A:123
B:456
C:789
D:1011
A:1213
B:1415
C:1617
D:1819
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use Python 3.6+, then it will use the insertion order, though I am not sure if this works for JSON-parsing as well.

Otherwise, you could try first sorting the keys and loop over those.

I suppose using an `OrderedDict` would not be what you are looking for?

Lastly, perhaps you should try to avoid depending on the order in the further part of code (since that is under your control).